# When online my webpage becomes unresponsive on my macbook-pro osx?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

When online my webpage becomes unresponsive, particularly when I click on a link, is there a fix? I have a MacBook-Pro osx 10.7.4 about a year old.  This is not a new problem and I have been blaming it on my router but the signal is strong and disconnecting from wi-fi and then reconnecting seems to get things going again. It happens intermittently and I can't figure out what is causing it.  Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Which browser are you using?

I was experiencing the same issue on Chrome, all I did was

- Go into Chrome - Preferences
- Go to advanced settings
- Un-tick the box "Predict network actions to improve page load performance"
- Restarted Chrome

Then it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly related to [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) problems. Can you check in your terminal if the following commands produce immediately a response? You can also check this with some other hostnames, because the responses may be cached on your local machine.

```
nslookup www.apple.com
nslookup apple.stackexchange.com
```

Is the DNS server in your network settings set correctly?